# How to add items in listview using thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have a simple code but this is not working how to fix this issue the thread is running but listview is not updating what is the problem can anyone just explain it?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Problems", 80);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Data", 120);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Registry Key", 130);
        listView1.Columns.Add("users", 80);
        Thread childThread = new Thread(getlist);
        childThread.Start();
    }
    public void getlist()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            add("a", "b", "c", "d");
        }

    }
    public void add(string prob, string reg, string data, string user)
    {
        String[] row = { prob, reg, data, user };
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
        ListViewItem v = listView1.Items.Add(item);

        item.Checked = true;

    }
```

Comment: You forgat to start the thread. `childThread.Start()`

Comment: Also you will face a problem which its solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=1)

Comment: What happens if you run code directly on the UI thread (as it should be anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few issues.

1. You created a thread but not called to start.
2. Even if you start the thread it *won't* work because you are not allowed to update controls from other thread than one created the controls (Often called `UI` Thread), code throws `cross-thread` error.

Fixing these two issues, your code should look like

.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    listView1.Columns.Add("Problems", 80);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Data", 120);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Registry Key", 130);
    listView1.Columns.Add("users", 80);
    Thread childThread = new Thread(getlist);
    childThread.Start();
}
public void getlist()
{
    add("a", "b", "c", "d");
}
public void add(string prob, string reg, string data, string user)
{
    String[] row = { prob, reg, data, user };

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);


    if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
         listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
         {
             listView1.Items.Add(item);
             item.Checked = true;

         }));
    }   
    else
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        item.Checked = true;
    } 


}
```

Comment: Actually i am reading some registry but when i am starting a new thread the value comes vithin add(); but the listview is not updating y this happens i have used your code also but same problem and have use thread.start();

Comment: I guess, I got what is happening. Probably the control's handle does not yet exist, InvokeRequired searches up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle. If no appropriate handle can be found, the InvokeRequired method returns false. Check to see if `InvokeRequired` is returning `false`

Comment: have edited the code what i am doing is i am using a for loop there please see it and help me

Comment: That's not an issue, try placing `Application.DoEvents()` after you started the thread.